# JSR/RET are not supported with computeFrames option - Android Studio 4.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Build fails with "JSR/RET are not supported with computeFrames option",

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        //noinspection DifferentKotlinGradleVersion
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.6.1'
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.35'
        // Replace the standard Performance Monitoring plugin dependency line, as follows:
        classpath('com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.0') {
            exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
        }
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/google/flexbox-layout/' }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Android studio version - 4.2.1,
This issue occurs after upgrading gradle and android version to 4.2.1,

I have tried with `Run with --stacktrace` but i cannot get error description other than the above one.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Any luck with this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue now. Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 3):

If you still have the trouble, perhaps this may help you

Remove the dependence for firebase perfomance and any use of it

I had the same message when tried to generate apk or rebuild my project

Then i removed that dependency and it worked normally

At the moment, i'm still doing some research about the origin of that failure, i'll update the answer if i find more info about the origin